# can you run a shell command via nohup at later time?

Tags: ssh, bash, nohup

I'd like to run a script at 6pm on a remote server but don't want to wait around to trigger it. I don't want to use cron since it's a one time deal.

Can I do something like "nohup myscript &" with a "sleep" or "after" command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you aren't looking for something like [at](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at).

Comment: I think you're right! would you mind posting the right syntax? is it "nohup script.sh | at now +4 hours &" ? (just a guess, clearly!

thanks

Comment: at queues and executes whatever you give it on stdin, so syntax is e.g. 'echo script.sh | at now +4 hours'.  you don't need nohup with at.  see the man page for at for more details.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `at` (`man at`) command to do this, and then you don't need the nohup.

If you really wanted to, you could:

```
nohup bash -c 'sleep 5; command' &
```

But you might be better off running the command in screen and then use sleep before it so you can easily check the output.

Comment: Thanks for this! I don't have permission to run `at` evidently, but am able to run sleep. So I came up with this monstrosity:
`nohup bash -c 'sleep $((\`date -d "Wed Aug 9 09:15:00 CDT 2017" +%s\` - \`date +%s\`)); nice mpstat -P ALL 2 12300 > mpstat.log' &`

Answer (score 1):

You could create another shell script that does the sleep then runs your command.

```
cat > x.sh
sleep 5
yourcommand.sh
^D

nohup x.sh &
```